# Folding braces in Emacs/AucTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex, code-folding

I have some code looking like this:

```
142  \newcommand*\john[2]{
143    blah blah blah blah
144    blah blah
145    blah blah blah
146    blah
147  }
148
149  \newcommand*\peter[3]{
150    blah blah
151  }
```

It would be great if I could double-click (or ctrl-click, or whatever) on the `{` on line 142, or the `}` on line 147, to make the definition of `\john` "fold up", like so:

```
142  \newcommand*\john[2]{ ... }
148
149  \newcommand*\peter[3]{
150    blah blah
151  }
```

Does (or could) this feature exist? It would be rather handy when working with large files.

Comment: The feature exists (see http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Folding.html ), but it seems to require some tweaking in order to work on braces (instead of the macro itself).

Comment: Thanks @T.Verron, yes I read a little about that. As you say, the machinery is all in place, we just needs an emacs wiz to swoop in...

Comment: Also, if your use-case is specifically a file with lots of `\newcommand`s, you may find documentation about emacs tags interesting: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should work (requires AUCTeX and you first need to enable `TeX-fold-mode` with <kbd>C-c C-o C-f</kbd> or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `TeX-fold-mode`)

```lisp
(defun mg-TeX-fold-brace ()
  "Hide the group in which point currently is located with \"{...}\"."
  (interactive)
  (let ((opening-brace (TeX-find-opening-brace))
    (closing-brace (TeX-find-closing-brace))
    priority ov)
    (if (and opening-brace closing-brace)
    (progn
      (setq priority (TeX-overlay-prioritize opening-brace closing-brace))
      (setq ov (make-overlay opening-brace closing-brace
                 (current-buffer) t nil))
      (overlay-put ov 'category 'TeX-fold)
      (overlay-put ov 'priority priority)
      (overlay-put ov 'evaporate t)
      (overlay-put ov 'TeX-fold-display-string-spec "{...}")
      (TeX-fold-hide-item ov))
      (message "No group found"))))

;; Bind the function to C-c C-o p
(eval-after-load "tex-fold"
  '(define-key TeX-fold-keymap "p" 'mg-TeX-fold-brace))
```

> [image]

Point must be placed between braces, braces excluded.  I've almost copy-pasted `TeX-fold-make-overlay` defined in [`tex-fold.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/tex-fold.el).  You can call this function with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `mg-TeX-fold-brace` or bind it to your favorite key binding.  I used <kbd>C-c C-o p</kbd> in the example, `TeX-fold-mode` automatically prefixes the defined key with <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd>.

To automatically unfold braces move point between them, instead to permanently show the braces use <kbd>C-c C-o i</kbd> or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `TeX-fold-clearout-item`.

Starting from this function it's possible to write a function for folding whatever you want.  What you need is to find a way for searching the points where folding starts and ends.  In this case I used the AUCTeX functions `TeX-find-{opening,closing}-brace` for finding the two braces.  In the line

```lisp
(overlay-put ov 'TeX-fold-display-string-spec "{...}")
```

you can set the string with which the folded region will be replaced.

Comment: +1. Can you please elaborate on -- You can bind this function to your favorite key binding ? Also, how do we unfold things?

Comment: @Harish I'm on mobile, but describe-function local-set-key.

Comment: @HarishKumar I think something like `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c p") 'mg-TeX-fold-brace)` would do the trick.

Comment: @HarishKumar I've added instructions on how to bind that function to a key binding in `TeX-mode` and how to unfold braces. @JohnWickerson I prefer to bind this function to the AUCTeX specific key map `;-)`.

Comment: This works really well. Thanks so much giordano!

Comment: When I quit and re-open Aquamacs, I get the warning `An error occurred while loading .emacs: Symbol's value as variable is void: TeX-mode-map.` Any guess as to what I've done wrong?

Comment: Try this: `(eval-after-load "tex-fold" '(define-key TeX-fold-keymap "p" 'mg-TeX-fold-brace))` instead of the simple `(define-key ...)`. If this works I'll update the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Giordano solution works perfectly but the fold will be gone after the buffer killed. Each time you want to fold, you need to run the function again.

I have another solution to automatically fold everything you want.
I use this function with comments.
Example:

```
% Why I write this paragraph in latex \begin{fold}
% comment
% another comment
% \end{fold}
```

or You want to fold paragraph or other

```
% Paragraph that explains about A \begin{fold}
A is a letter. Another sentence. End of paragraph.
% \end{fold}
```

When nyou run this function. M-x latex-fold-foo
It will fold everythig that \begin{fold} \end{fold}

The result like this

```
% Why I write this paragraph in latex [fold]
% Paragraph that explains about A [fold]
```

Each time you move your cursor to the folded paragraph, It will open it temporarily.
If you want to remove the fold, use C-c C-o i

```
(defun latex-fold-foo ()
  (interactive)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward (format "begin{fold}") nil t)
        (TeX-fold-env))))
```

My workflow is

1. Open the buffer
2. Run the function to automatically fold everything
3. C-c C-o i to delete the fold if u want to edit it and see it permanently