# Maintain display of arguments for certain folded environments with AUCTeX

Tags: environments, emacs, auctex, code-folding

When working with some environments (`function` and friends from `l3doc` prompted this), it is desirable to have the environment's arguments visible at all times:

```
Some text that, in reality, shouldn't be here in an l3doc
\begin{function}{\tl_new:N}
  Some documentation...
\end{function}
more inappropriate text
```

When folding this using <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-o</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd>, everything goes away (which is useful for environments like `minipage`, etc.):

```
Some text that, in reality, shouldn't be here in an l3doc
  [function]
more inappropriate text
```

Is there any way to turn this into the following for *certain* environments?

```
Some text that, in reality, shouldn't be here in an l3doc
  [function]{\tl_new:N}
more inappropriate text
```

(If only a solution for *all* environments exists easily, I can manage with turning on/off the mode.)

---

If the solution would be similar, it would be *really* cool if you could have some sort of marker, say `%!!`, that would always stay visible in folded environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start of a solution, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117073/31416)

```lisp
(defun mg-TeX-fold-environment-with-argument ()
  "Hide the current environment with \"[environment]{argument}\"."
  (interactive)
  (if (equal (LaTeX-current-environment) "function")
      (let ((env-end (save-excursion
               (LaTeX-find-matching-end)
               (point)))
        env-start priority ov)
    (setq env-start (save-excursion
              (LaTeX-find-matching-begin)
              (looking-at "\\\\begin{function}\\({[^}]*}\\)")
              (point)))
    (if (and env-start env-end)
        (progn
          (setq priority (TeX-overlay-prioritize env-start env-end))
          (setq ov (make-overlay env-start env-end
                     (current-buffer) t nil))
          (overlay-put ov 'category 'TeX-fold)
          (overlay-put ov 'priority priority)
          (overlay-put ov 'evaporate t)
          (overlay-put ov 'TeX-fold-display-string-spec
               (concat "[function]" (match-string-no-properties 1)))
          (TeX-fold-hide-item ov))
      (message "No environment found")))))
```

Comment: This is really cool!  Would you mind if I took a crack at generalizing it and posting this to GitHub?

Comment: No, as long as you attribute it (though I shamelessly stole the code from the `TeX-fold-make-overlay` function), this site is under CC-BY-SA after all `;-)`